# In route 53 AWS, how to handle duplicate subdomain

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am creating dynamic subdomain using Java API's for Amazon route 53. Is there any way I could find the subdomain pre-exists in the domain using the API's of RecordSet or Route53.

For example, I will dynamically create sub-domains, like

- abc(abc.example.com)
- xyz(xyz.example.com)

What happens when I add the abc, xyz again or how could I find the subdomain is already active in the RecordSet using java API's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`listResourceRecordSets()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/AmazonRoute53.html#listResourceRecordSets-com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.ListResourceRecordSetsRequest-) to get a list of record sets for your hosted zone, and check if the subdomain is already in that list. You might be able to filter that list to get just your requested subdomain with [`ListResourceRecordSetsRequest.withStartRecordName()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/ListResourceRecordSetsRequest.html#withStartRecordName-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Could you let me know what happens when I try to add the same name?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/AmazonRoute53.html#changeResourceRecordSets-com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest-), `changeResourceRecordSets` method is used in AWS Route53 JavaSDK to Create, Change and Delete record sets. If you try to add an existing record set, it will result in no modification (Since the record set exists and change is null).

Comment: But via the api it throws an error, so how could I differentiate this in the AmazonRoute53Client?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the listResourceRecordSets() as mentioned by kichik. If you try to add the same resource again it will throw an [com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.InvalidChangeBatchException](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/InvalidChangeBatchException.html) containing the exception message

```
Tried to create resource record set [name='abc.example.com.', type='CNAME'] but it already exists (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidChangeBatch; Request ID: **********)
```